# connect two keyboards to speaker and possibly computer sometimes

Tags: keyboard, speakers, mixer

I have two keyboards (well, one digital piano and one synthesizer) that both have stereo out jack outputs. How can I connect both to one set of speakers so that I will also be able to record everything on a computer occasionally?

I have nord monitors for the speakers, they take two mono inputs, left and right.

I also have an audio interface that I use to record the guitar sometimes. It's the UA Arrow and has two in and two out connections as well as headphone and guitar. But that's not enough to hook up my two keyboards because each has 2 out jacks...

I don't think I can I make a connection like keyboard1->keyboard2->speakers because both keyboard's only in connection is midi in and I want to move the sound and not just the midi data.

What about a DI box?

Comment: Unless these are powered speakers, you'll need an amp. too.

Comment: Ill go with the mixer. I was thinking of Behringer MX 400 which has enough inputs but it outputs just in mono, so I might get a Xenyx 502

Comment: You will still need an amp if the speakers are passive! And it's worth considering an 802 to make it futureproof. Mics, guitars, another keyboard - you never know.

Comment: I think they're active speakers

Comment: Active speakers need to be plugged into mains power  normally.

Comment: Is there a difference between “mains” power and just “power”?

Comment: Not particularly - mains power is from the socket in the wall, power may be from batteries, or a wall wart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case you'll have to buy something. You have basically two options: (1) mixer, or (2) new audio interface with more inputs and routing options.

If you want to keep your current audio interface, you could use a mixer that has enough inputs for all of your devices, and a possibility to route the signals you want to record into the audio interface, and route the output of your audio interface to the monitor speakers and headphones *without* routing them to the audio interface's input, which would create a feedback loop. One way to do this is with two "aux" outputs. Each channel you want to be able to record, you route to an aux output. And the audio interface's output, you connect to an input that you do *not* send to the mixer's aux outputs. This setup can be nice, and sometimes it's handy to have some tactile control over what's happening. And you'll be able to play, mix and change levels etc. without having your computer switched on or even connected at all. But you'll have more stuff on your desk, more cables and everything ... and you won't be able to record all of the devices on separate tracks simultaneously.

A different kind of option is a new audio interface that has more inputs, for example Steinberg UR44 or Focusrite Scarlett 6i6 or something even larger. With a bigger audio interface, you can have all your devices connected and routed to separate tracks in a recording software all the time. Reading your description, this might not be needed really. But then again, if you want to play guitar as well - depending on what kind of guitar it is, you might want to take advantage of an audio interface's "Hi-Z" inputs, which are needed for many electric guitars and basses.